# How can I check if a URL param is present before providing it in jQuery JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm passing through a bunch of parameters to an API Url, however the last one I would like to dynamically set only if the URL parameter 'vendor' is present.

I know how to do this in PHP, but how could I do this here?

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    "token": ev.token.id,
    "shippingAddress": ev.shippingAddress,
    "payerName": ev.payerName,
    "payerEmail": ev.payerEmail,
    "payerPhone": ev.payerPhone,
    "amount": parseInt(amount),
    "currency": 'GBP',
    "narative": "ntjersey",
    "notes": "",
    "ccid": "52FE039A8B53",
    "userid": vendor
}),
```

The last line 'userid' and the value of the var vendor is what I want to only supply if the URL parameter 'vendor' exists. Can anyone help if there's a way just to add a simple check to this line?

Similar to PHP doing an `echo isset($_GET['vendor']) ? $_GET['vendor'] : null;` is basically what I'm looking for please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear but if you only want to send the userid if vendor is defined, you can use the code below.

```
let params = 
{
    "token": ev.token.id,
    "shippingAddress": ev.shippingAddress,
    "payerName": ev.payerName,
    "payerEmail": ev.payerEmail,
    "payerPhone": ev.payerPhone,
    "amount": parseInt(amount),
    "currency": 'GBP',
    "narative": "ntjersey",
    "notes": "",
    "ccid": "52FE039A8B53",
    "userid": vendor
};
if(typeof vendor !== 'undefined')
    params.userid = vendor;

body: JSON.stringify(params),
```

If you want to set the user id to NULL if vendor is undefined you can just change

```
body: JSON.stringify({
    "token": ev.token.id,
    "shippingAddress": ev.shippingAddress,
    "payerName": ev.payerName,
    "payerEmail": ev.payerEmail,
    "payerPhone": ev.payerPhone,
    "amount": parseInt(amount),
    "currency": 'GBP',
    "narative": "ntjersey",
    "notes": "",
    "ccid": "52FE039A8B53",
    "userid": typeof vendor == 'undefined' ? : null : vendor
}),
```

If the vendor variable has no entry it can be null or an empty string. So you can also check on

```
if(typeof vendor != 'undefined' && vendor != null && vendor.length != 0)
    params.userid = vendor;
```

Comment: Hi there, this is a great answer and does resolve my initial question, however I'm now being asked if it can filter if someone provides no value to the parameter e.g. ?vendor= (and then leaves it blank). How could this be catered for, as the vendor param will be defined, but with no value now. Thanks again.